# Why is EF Core performing an extra SELECT COUNT(*) ? (Telerik, KENDO, ToDataSourceResult)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm working on a small EF Core 2.1 webbapplication and noticed that EF Core seem to perform an extra COUNT(*) everytime I read an entity.
For example:

```
var analysis = _context.Analyses.Where(p => p.CommitmentId == commitmentId).AsNoTracking();
```

Will result in this in my VS2019 output window:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM [ANALYSES] AS [p]
WHERE [p].[CommitmentId] = @__commitmentId_0
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:Information: Executed DbCommand (36ms) [Parameters=[@__commitmentId_0='?' (DbType = Int32), @__p_1='?' (DbType = Int32), @__p_2='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']

SELECT [p].[Id], [p].[Amount] [...]
FROM [ANALYSES] AS [p]
WHERE [p].[CommitmentId] = @__commitmentId_0
ORDER BY (SELECT 1)
```

I guess this should be a really basic question, but I've not been able to find a way to disable this "feature".

How do I tell EF Core not to perform this unwanted Count operation?

**ANSWER**

As stated by TomTom in the comments the code above does not trigger any SQL-command. Instead that is done by the following line:

```
return Json(analysis.ToDataSourceResult(request));
```

The ToDataSoureResult by Telerik is performing this extra count, so it has nothing to do with EF Core.
By performing a ToList() on the

```
var analysis = _context.Analyses.Where(p => p.CommitmentId == commitmentId).AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

the ToDataSourceResult stopped to executing that extra COUNT()

Comment: EF Core 2.1 is End Of Life. Consider to update at least to 3.1.

Comment: Could be because of IEnumerable, just do IQueryable query = _context.Analyses; var analysis = query.Where(p => p.CommitmentId == commitmentId).AsNoTracking();

Comment: I agree with @SvyatoslavDanyliv, use  3.1 instead.

Comment: Looks like there is something additional applied in your code to the shown query. Most likely pagination, like PagedList?

Comment: Ah, sorry, but that line of code does NOT trigger ANY sql - you need a materialization due to EF delayed LINQ execution. WIthout seeing the exact code, it can not be answered. Yes, 3.1 should be used, but the issue here is more fundamental. analysis is still a query and may well be used twice.